# Progressive Web App in Chrome Custom Tab

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, chrome-custom-tabs, manifest.json

I am building a Progressive Web App. When I open it in the Chrome browser, I correctly see the "add to home screen" option come up in a bottom sheet. However, when I open my app in a Chrome Custom tab, the "add to home screen" bottom sheet is not appearing.

Does anyone know if Chrome Custom tabs supports the Progressive Web Apps manifest?

Update: I've filed a bug against Chromium for this issue https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=731171#c2

Answer (score 4):

Chrome Custom Tabs has the ability to show an "Add to Homescreen" menu item, at least in recent builds of Chrome.

I can confirm that manually selecting the "Add to Homescreen" menu item will make use of the web app manifest data when creating the homescreen item.

However, I don't believe that the logic for automatically triggering the [Web App Install Banner](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/app-install-banners/) is enabled for page views with Chrome Custom Tab at this time—I experimented a bit and never got the banner to appear, at least.